# How to install ZF2 in ubuntu 12.04 + virtual host + mod_rewrite

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, ubuntu, zend-framework2

I installed zf2 skeleton application and some modules like zfcuser and zfcBase from  https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser and I installed it successfully in my local at the end I ran 192.168.3.12/myproject/user but I found  404 not found error always I have to run 192.168.3.12/myproject/public/user so I found there are lot of people are telling about to make virtual host I am not able to get my to run zf2 installation with virtual host

Please let me know the proper solution. I just want to install zf2 with the help of virtual host.

Comment: Mod_rewrite is enabled but do you have rewrite rules set up?

Comment: By htaccess? it is already there by default in ZF2...

Comment: should it be 192.168.3.12/user  ?

Comment: how is it possible? I mean without running my project how can I get my module run (user is the module which I installed)

Comment: ZF2 is a completely different animal when compared to ZF1 particularly where modules are concerned. Make sure you at least run through the 'Getting Started' tutorial in the ZF2 documentation. Unlike ZF1 the module url's don't exist in ZF2 until you add the module to the module list and configure the url's you intend to use to access the module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry for late Answer I have done it some time ago you can do it with below way.

1. Install zf2 in the /var/www directory assume project name is site1.
2. Enable mod_rewrite with this command **sudo a2enmod rewrite**
3. Configure virtual host and host file **(remember this is compulsory must do it)**

   **a**.Copy the current default setting found in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default and name it the same as your new site.

   ```
   eg. cp /etc/apache2/sites-available/default /etc/apache2/sites-available/site1
   ```

   **b.** Edit the new config files for each site using your preferred text editor. Add the line ServerName server1 right below the ServerAdmin line and change both DocumentRoot and Directory to point to your new sites.
   This is what it should look like :

   ```
   /etc/apache2/sites-available/site1
   ```

   **c.**

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
     ServerName test.zf2.com
     DocumentRoot /var/www/site1/public
     <Directory />
       Options FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/site1/public/>
       Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
       AllowOverride All
       Order allow,deny
       allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
   </VirtualHost>
   ```

   **d.**  run this command

   ```
   sudo a2ensite site1
   ```

   **e.**  restart apache

   ```
    sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload
   ```

4.Edit host file set your new host name and IP address to it.

run

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

set this data

```
YOUR_IP_ADDRESS    test.zf2.com
```

Thatz it!!!! hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure within your Apache config that the root directory of your website points to the 'Your_Skeleton_App_Path/**public**'. The rewrite rules are set only for the public folder

The root folder of the skeleton directory does not contain any index.php file (thus the 404 error)

(I wish i could have made this answer only a comment, but i can't comment yet)