# Setting up vhost for Zend application

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, config, vhosts

I am currently taking over a PHP Zend project and i am having trouble setting the vhost up for it in mamp on my local machine. I have it working to an extent, meaning it going to the index page and executes some PHP, however non of the links are working nor is it finding the rout folder files (css, js and images) which is a pain in my backside. I have never worked with Zend before so i am unaware if i am missing something out.

Here is my vhost settings for the project...

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "/Users/john/Sites/application-website/public/"
ServerName gc.dev
#RewriteEngine on
<Directory "/Users/john/Sites/application-website/public/">
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from All
</Directory>
```

If any one has any ideas it would be a great help, thank you in advance.

htaccess in public/

```
       # Enable rewrite engine
       RewriteEngine On
       RewriteBase /

       # The following rule tells Apache that if the requested filename
       # exists, simply serve it.
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
       RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

       # Redirect to www
       RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
       RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
       RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
       RewriteRule . http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

       # Remove trailing slash
       RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
       RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ http%1://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

       # Redirect index.php to /
       RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
       RewriteRule ^index.php$ http%1://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [R=301,L]

       RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: can you show us the *.htaccess* file in the *public* directory? You should have one

Comment: have you activated mod_rewrite? run `sudo a2enmod rewrite`

Comment: I have edited the question so you can see the htaccess file content

Comment: see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13538543/how-to-install-zf2-in-ubuntu-12-04-virtual-host-mod-rewrite?#answer-15082271

Comment: Pretty much followed that but still no change

Comment: You said the index url work ??

Comment: If it's not finding the css/images/js files, you have bigger problems - what happens when you try and access those?

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you have mod_rewrite enabled on Apache usually on your httpd.conf file
2. The virtual host to the following -

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
       DocumentRoot /Users/john/Sites/application-website/public
       ServerName gc.dev
       <Directory /Users/john/Sites/application-website/public>
           DirectoryIndex index.php
           AllowOverride All
           Order allow,deny
           Allow from all
       </Directory>
   </VirtualHost>
   ```
3. Your .htaccess looks like the following (should be located at public/.htaccess) -

   ```
   RewriteEngine On
   # The following rule tells Apache that if the requested filename
   # exists, simply serve it.
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
   RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
   # The following rewrites all other queries to index.php. The
   # condition ensures that if you are using Apache aliases to do
   # mass virtual hosting, the base path will be prepended to
   # allow proper resolution of the index.php file; it will work
   # in non-aliased environments as well, providing a safe, one-size
   # fits all solution.
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::\2$
   RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you need to add the following lines in your .htaccess file.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [NC,L]
```

That means, with your code -

```
# Enable rewrite engine
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# The following rule tells Apache that if the requested filename
# exists, simply serve it.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

# Redirect to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule . http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ http%1://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect index.php to /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^index.php$ http%1://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: This has done something like it seems the images have started to show up however all the styles/scripts etc are still not :S

Comment: We have a little progress here i have sorted the issue out with the public folder routing with the images/css/js. The only issue now is when i click out side 'gc.dev/' for example 'gc.dev/blog/ it wont find anything.